# OpenGL ES: glDeleteFramebuffers succeeds even with no current Context?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Target: Android API >=23, OpenGL ES 2.

The following code

```
 private void deleteFBO()
    {
    android.util.Log.e("FBO", "deleting "+mFramebufferID);

    int[] textureIds = new int[1];
    int[] mFBORenderToTexture = new int[1];

    textureIds[0] = mTextureID;
    mFBORenderToTexture[0] = mFramebufferID;

    if( GLES20.glGetError()!=GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR )
      android.util.Log.e("FBO", "error before deleting");

    GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
    GLES20.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, mFBORenderToTexture, 0);

    if( GLES20.glGetError()!=GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR )
      android.util.Log.e("FBO", "error after deleting");
    }
```

doesn't give me any errors (i.e. I cannot see the 'error before/after deleting') even though it is for sure called from a thread which does NOT hold any OpenGL contexts.

How is that possible? Or maybe the glDelete() calls really DO fail, but my code fails to detect this?

Seems like I don't understand WHICH OpenGL calls need to be made when holding the context? Certainly glDrawArrays gives me an error when I try to call it without holding the context, and I thought I need to be holding it in every single case, including the two glDelete*() above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHICH OpenGL calls need to be made when holding the context?

All of them. Which includes `glGetError()`. This means that your error checks themselves are invalid if there is no current context.

Even though, I found some claims that `glGetError()` returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` if there is no current context. But I have not been able to find that behavior defined in the spec. So until somebody shows me otherwise, I'll stick to my claim that calling `glGetError()` without a current context will give undefined (i.e. implementation dependent) results.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it - I managed to prove glGetError() itself fails. This is both on an Android emulator and my Nexus 4.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate actually. How do I detect failed OpenGL calls in this situation then? Here with the glDelete() silently failing, the app still seems to be running but the memory is of course not released...

Comment: Don't write buggy applications - it's not a situation you should accidentally have to handle at run-time. If you have to add debug checks just add assertions on `eglGetCurrentContext()` not returning `EGL_NO_CONTEXT`.

Comment: Hmm, not writing buggy applications is not an option I am afraid :) I am writing a kind of OpenGL library and I simply don't know from which thread my users are going to call various methods (well, those that need to be called from a thread holding the context are of course IMHO clearly marked as such, but I'd rather independently re-assure myself that this is indeed the case)

Comment: Looks like I'd need to add a 'debug' flag then and if this is switched on, in every method which needs to be called when holding the context, do a 'eglGetCurrentContext()' ?